# Preserving display of drop-down menu when mouse leaves hover div controlling menu

Tags: jquery, hover, slidetoggle

I have a simple drop-down menu that is controlled using the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img.menu_class').hover(function () {
    $('.the_menu').slideToggle('medium');
    });
});
```

I can't work out how to continue to display the div that is revealed, i.e. ".the_menu", when the mouse leaves the 'img.menu_class' div but stays in the ".the_menu" div.  It needs to be preserved whilst the mouse is in either of these divs.

You can see the menu in its current state [here](http://salliannputman.com/).  Just hover on the main nav bar (it's just an image at the moment) to see the drop-down menu.

Could someone help with this?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `hover()` you can switch to `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` and change the markup a bit.

### Example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu_class">
  <img src="http://salliannputman.com/images/nav.png">
  <div class="submenu" style="display: none">
    <img src="http://salliannputman.com/images/nav3.png" />
  </div>     
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('img.menu_class').mouseenter(function() {
  $('img.submenu').slideDown('medium');
});
$('img.menu_class').mouseleave(function() {
  $('img.submenu').slideUp('medium');
});
```

**[HERE](http://jsbin.com/irajoq/4/edit)** is the working code.

Comment: And the sub-nav is still there even if you hover -after- some other MAIN nav

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTimeout` to create a delay in hiding the menu:

```
$(function () {
    var myTimer,
        myDelay = 100;

    $('img.menu_class, .the_menu').hover(function () { 

        //when either a `img.menu_class` or a `.the_menu` element is hovered over, clear the timeout to hide the menu and slide the menu into view if it aleady isn't
        clearTimeout(myTimer);
        $('.the_menu').stop(true, true).slideDown('medium');
    },
    function () {

        //when either a `img.menu_class` or a `.the_menu` element is hovered out, set a timeout to hide the menu
        myTimer = setTimeout(function () {$('.the_menu').stop(true, true).slideUp('medium');}, myDelay);
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7vrGu/2/

Comment: I like the delay in hiding the menu.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

when you call `hover` with just one argument it runs the handler function you pass in on both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. I.e. is it slideToggling ".the_menu" twice - once when you `mouseover`, once when you `mouseleave`: 
http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2

You need to call `hover` with two arguments, pass a separate handler function to call on `mouseleave`. 
http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1

example:

```
$('img.menu_class').hover(function () {
        $('.the_menu').slideDown('medium');
    }, function() {
        // do something else in mouseleave - you don't necessarily want to slideUp ".the_menu" yet
    });
```